# Graded commutator for vector space over field

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

My lecturer said something like when $V$ is a vector space over a field, the graded commutator $$[a,b]=ab-(-1)^{|a||b|}ba$$
becomes $[a,b]=ab+ba$.

Why is this so? I don't really understand.

Thanks.

Comment: This needs more context before we can make any sense out of it. If $a$ and $b$ are just elements of a vector space $V$, then a product like $ab$ has no meaning in general. Perhaps this is supposed to be the product in the tensor algebra? In that case, the graded commutator makes sense, and $a$ and $b$ are probably to be considered as elements of degree $1$ in the tensor product. Your formula follows because $|a|=|b|=1$ in that case.